# Displaying SVG inline when part of content: url() and changing its colour

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a module where I want the user to be able to select what arrow type (list-style) they want. This option is a `colorpicker`, so if a user choses a blue HEX, the `svg` will `stroke: blue`.

However, I'm unsure on how this can be achieved when the `li` arrow is being printed via the before pseudo.

For example, here is my markup:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: url("images/bullet-point.svg");
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <ul>
   <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

`bullet-point.svg` looks like this:

```css
.st0{
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  enable-background:new;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 13 12" style="enable-background:new 0 0 13 12;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px">
<polyline class="st0" points="1,1 6,6 1,11 "/>
<polyline class="st0" points="7,1 12,6 7,11 "/>
</svg>
```

What I'm trying to do (and what I think is the best approach here, I may be wrong), is to print `bullet-point.svg` inline. I.e. is it possible for ...

```
content: url("images/bullet-point.svg");
```

... to become (something equivalent to):

```
 content: url(<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 13 12" style="enable-background:new 0 0 13 12;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px"><polyline class="st0" points="1,1 6,6 1,11 "/><polyline class="st0" points="7,1 12,6 7,11 "/></svg>);
```

I think this way, I'll be able to manipulate the `.st0` class to change it's `stroke` to the value the user selects in the `colorpicker`.

Comment: _“... to become (something equivalent to)”_ - your research keyword is _Data URI_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be using `content: "\0bb";` also you can use  `"\0226b"` instead.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\0bb";
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <ul>
   <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use the svg as data uri:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ul li:before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 13 12' width='15px'%3E%3Cg stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' fill='none' stroke-width='2' stroke='blue'%3E%3Cpolyline points='1,1 6,6 1,11 '/%3E%3Cpolyline points='7,1 12,6 7,11 '/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <ul>
   <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

In order to transform the svg to data uri you can use this [SVG-encoder](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/JDqvs)

Comment: Didn't even think about going about things as you did in the first approach! Also thanks for showing me both approaches, much appreciated :)